# Android Firebase Create User

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i was doing the creating of users shown in the firebase guide(https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/login/password.html) and i cant seem to create a user in the login&auth email andpassword.

i can manually create and event and use the ref.removeUser to remove the user using my android device but i cant seam to create new user using my android device(no error shown)

thanks a bunch for all your help

JAR version : firebase-client-android-2.1.0.jar

below is my onCreate function:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com/");

    ref.createUser("bobtony@firebase.com", "correcthorsebatterystaple", new Firebase.ResultHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // user was created
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pass",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            // there was an error]
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fail",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    //

}
```

Comment: When you ran the above code, did you replace the `<YOUR-FIREBASE>` with the name of your actual Firebase?

Comment: yes of course. i can remove the user in my android device that i manually added using the "Add New User" in the login & auth tab

Comment: Are either of the `onSuccess()` or `onError()` callbacks invoked? Anything show up in the logs?

Comment: @RobDiMarco sorry but i didnt check the logs
This showed up in the logs

 `code`Could not find method org.shaded.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity.<init>, referenced from method com.firebase.client.utilities.HttpUtilities.addMethodParams  `code`

Comment: and also
 `code` VFY: unable to resolve direct method 21714: Lorg/shaded/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity;.<init> (Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)V  `code`

Comment: @user1193041 looks like there is quite a bit more due diligence you could do here. At the very least, getting a stack trace into the question, now that you know the correct errors, and showing the relevant code that triggers those lines seems critical.

Comment: This is a bug in our Firebase library, we'll release a fix later today.

Comment: @Kato i am sorry cause i am still new at stackoverflow and thank you very much for the feedback :)

Comment: thanks everyone :) working on 2.1.1